# How to make this table scrollable and header fixed Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Hello i have tried various implementation of bootstrap fixed header and body scroll but nothing worked out for me.Can anybody help to how to get this done.

[Jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/yqgB5/39/)

```
<table class="table  table-striped  table-bordered table-fixedheader">
<thead>
<tr class="success">
<th>Answer</th>
<th>Total</th>
<th>PCP</th>
<th>OB/GYN</th>
<th>PAIN</th>
<th>Other</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody style="height:100px"><tr><td>Alabama</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>2</td>
<td></td>
<td>1</td>
<td></td></tr><tr><td>Arizona</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>3</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td></tr><tr><td>California</td>
<td>35</td>
<td>18</td>
<td>9</td>
<td>8</td>
<td></td></tr><tr><td>Colorado</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>2</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td></tr><tr><td>Connecticut</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>2</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td></tr><tr><td>District of Columbia</td>
<td>1</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td>1</td>
<td></td></tr><tr><td>Florida</td>
<td>20</td>
<td>16</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>3</td>
<td></td></tr><tr><td>Georgia</td>
<td>6</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>5</td>
<td></td>
<td></td></tr><tr><td>Illinois</td>
<td>12</td>
<td>8</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>2</td>
<td></td></tr><tr><td>Indiana</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>2</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td></tr><tr><td>Kansas</td>
<td>2</td>
<td></td>
<td>2</td>
<td></td>
<td></td></tr><tr><td>Kentucky</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td></tr><tr><td>Maryland</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>2</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td></tr><tr><td>Massachusetts</td>
<td>4</td>
<td>3</td>
<td></td>
<td>1</td>
<td></td></tr><tr><td>Michigan</td>
<td>5</td>
<td>4</td>
<td></td>
<td>1</td>
<td></td></tr><tr><td>Missouri</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>2</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td></tr><tr><td>Nevada</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td></tr><tr><td>New Jersey</td>
<td>14</td>
<td>7</td>
<td>4</td>
<td>3</td>
<td></td></tr><tr><td>New Mexico</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td></tr><tr><td>New York</td>
<td>25</td>
<td>13</td>
<td>5</td>
<td>7</td>
<td></td></tr><tr><td>North Carolina</td>
<td>6</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>4</td>
<td></td></tr><tr><td>Ohio</td>
<td>6</td>
<td>5</td>
<td>1</td>
<td></td>
<td></td></tr><tr><td>Pennsylvania</td>
<td>16</td>
<td>9</td>
<td>4</td>
<td>3</td>
<td></td></tr><tr><td>Tennessee</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>2</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td></tr><tr><td>Texas</td>
<td>20</td>
<td>10</td>
<td>5</td>
<td>5</td>
<td></td></tr><tr><td>Virginia</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>2</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td></tr><tr><td>Washington</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td></tr><tr><td>West Virginia</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td></tr><tr><td>Wisconsin</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td></tr></tbody>
</table>
```

Please dont mark this as duplicate. I have tried every other way,my table structure differs from others questions.

P:S: I am new here, feeling difficult to get this jfiddle link in this post.sorry for bad format

Comment: You need to include your code here too, not just a fiddle.

Comment: oh am sorry am new here.will update

Answer (score 0):

apply this code to css

```
tbody {
    background-color: #ddd;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
}
td {
    padding: 3px 10px;
}
thead > tr, tbody{
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if a class 'table-fixedheader' exists at all. I don't see that in Bootstrap 3.0. But you can use a jQuery plugin for this (http://fixedheadertable.com/).